# Are these infinitive and gerund clauses?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, catenative-verbs

Are these infinitive and gerund clauses?

**He agreed to give him the ball** - Here in this sentence, the infinitive clause is "to give him the ball" which is the object of the verb "agreed"? Am I right?

**He has problems repairing his car** - Here in this sentence, the gerund clause is "repairing his car" and it acts as an adverb to "has".

Did I understand the things correctly? Or there is something wrong?

Comment: No, @BoSsYyY -- the infinitival clause "to give him the ball" is not object, but **complement** of "agreed". The gerund-participial clause "repairing his car" is not an adverb but **complement** of "has".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [1] *He agreed* [*to give him the ball*].
>
> [2] *He has problems* [*repairing his car*].

The bracketed non-finite clauses are neither objects nor adverbs.

These are both catenative constructions. "Agree" and "have" are catenative verbs and the bracketed non-finite clauses are their catenenative complements.

The term 'catentative' is derived from the Latin word for 'chain', for the construction consists of a 'chain' of verbs in which all except the last have a non-finite complement.

Comment: 'repairing' the car looks like a complement of the noun 'problem'. The problem is 'repairing his car'.

Comment: @user178049 No, gerund-participials do not function as complement of a noun. And it's not a modifier either!

Comment: @BillJ Okay. So you say that in the first sentence "to give him the ball" is a complement to the verb. So if it's a complement of the verb and not object then it is possible to add an object to this sentence. Give an example of the verb complement and the object.

Comment: @BoSsYyY The complement clause "to give him the ball", has "him" as indirect object and "the ball" as direct object.

Comment: Thanks! What about the second sentence? Isn't "repairing his car" the participle clause that modifies the subject? Also, Could you tell me what is the infinitive in this sentence: "He allowed the kid to play". I think it is the direct object and "the kid" is the indirect.

Comment: @BoSsYyY No, it relates to verb "has". In "He allowed the kid to play", the infinitival clause is "to play". The noun phrase "the kid" is the syntactic object of "allowed" and the understood subject of the infinitival clause. "Kid" is called a 'raised object.

Comment: @BillJ But is the "to play" in the sentence still a catenative complement to "told"?

Comment: @BoSsYyY Yes, it is.

Comment: @BillJ Oke. Understood everything. Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @BillJ According to the information provided by Wikipedia the second verb (which is either "to infinitive" or a "gerund" or a "bare/base infinitive") and the object catenated to it is the object of the verb that the subject is performing. For example: "He deserves to win the cup", here "to win the cup" is the object of "deserves".

Comment: @BoSsYyY Well, you can believe Wiki if you like!!! Give me a link.

Comment: @BillJ https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs

Comment: @BoSsYyY Wiki is 100% wrong. They are clueless about catenatives. Anyway, if you want to believe them that's up to you.

Comment: @BillJ From where you got the information about the catenative verbs? Is there something like an official book for the English grammar?

Answer (score 0):

**He agreed to give him the ball**
You are correct. "To give him the ball" is an infinitive **phrase** that is acting as a noun and is the direct object of the verb "agreed".

**He has problems repairing his car**
This one is less clear. I would consider "repairing his car" to be a **participial** phrase acting as an adjective and modifying "problems."

I believe you could also make the case that "repairing his car" is a gerund **phrase** acting as a noun and an appositive to "problems" but I think the first is more likely.

A few comments.

I've never heard of an infinitive or gerund clause. In English grammar when I learned it, "clauses" were sentence units with subjects and predicates (verbs) and "phrases" were sentence units without predicates. Since infinitives and gerunds do not behave as verbs (remember, they are considered nouns), it is proper to call them "phrases".

Gerunds and infinitives are always nouns and therefore cannot behave adverbially. If an -ing word seems to be behaving as an adverb or an adjective, it is called a "participle".

Comment: Okay so When something with "ing" is acting like an adjective or an adverb it's "participle" and when something with "ing" is acting as a noun it is "gerund" but the to infinitives act as a nouns, adjectives and adverbs and they are still called to infinitives in all of their forms?

Comment: Infinitives (to <verb>) can only act as nouns to my knowledge. If you can come up with a contrary example please do, I'm interested.

Comment: "It is hard to find new friends" - here "to find new friends" is an adjective that modifies "It". Isn't it? Also, could you tell me in this sentence what is "done"?      The sentence is: "I have the homework done" Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BoSsYyY No, that's an extraposed construction in which the infinitival clause is a displaced subject. The displaced subject functions as the real subject in the non-extraposed construction: 'to find a new friend is hard'. 'Done' is a past-participle verb with a passive meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Infinitive phrases can function adverbially, contrary to what was stated above. Consider, for example, this sentence: He took grammar to improve his language skills. The infinitive phrase "to improve his language skills" is adverbial, modifying the main verb "took."  The best test for an adverbial infinitive phrase is to insert the words "in order" in front of it, i.e., He took grammar (in order) to improve his language skills.